# Save generated csv file to sub folder with php

Tags: php, csv, store, fopen

I have tried to store the created csv file to another subfolder instead of getting stored where the php-file is located but with no luck. Have anyone solved this by changing fopen? This is my code:

```
<?php

$data_array = array (
  array ('test', $_POST['test'],)
);

$csv = "col1,col2 \n";//Column headers
foreach ($data_array as $record){
$csv.= $record[0].','.$record[1]."\n"; //Append data to csv
}

$csv_handler = fopen ('order_'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.csv','w');

fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
fclose ($csv_handler);

echo 'Data saved to csvfile.csv';

?>
```

Comment: Avoid relative paths. It's pain for PHP to calculate them and often fails. Try using an absolute path instead

Comment: Try:
`$csv_handler = fopen ('subfolder/order_'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.csv','w');`

Comment: Why exactly doesn't it work? Do you get some kind of notice/warning/error? It could be that the folder doesn't exist and you need to create it first, or it's not writable.

Comment: Note: have a look to [`fputcsv()`](https://secure.php.net/fputcsv) to create CSV file, instead of create it manually.

Comment: Thank you Zoran, this worked. Tried this before but I didnt have the sufficient permissions to save to this folder locally